# Cannot detect FT2232H

Tags: usb, jtag, ftdi

I am using FT2232H for USB to JTAG communication. Cannot detect FT2232H in device manager and FTPROG. I am attaching my schematics for reference. I have used the similar schematics before in another board and it was working.
[image]

Comment: `I have used the similar schematics before` ... how are these schematics different?

Comment: Have you installed the drivers ? Go to the FTDI website download the suitable drivers and install them ... On some Windows versions there is no FTDI driver by default.

Comment: There used to be a problem with FT232 (USB -> UART) chips, because some Chinese factory began to produce them in abundance and the original manufacturer began to drop production. That's why he got pissed off and implemented in his drivers recognition of the chip's serial number and blocking support for counterfeit chips. And suddenly the non-original ICs stopped working because the original driver stopped supporting them. Do you have an IC from a reliable source? Maybe you got a counterfeit one?

Comment: By the way, this is the first time I see inductance between two grounds (L5 -> 3.9 uH). Are you sure about this solution? In my opinion, this is a mistake.